# Anonymous async function call

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to create anonymous async function?

Of course named function works:

```
const test = async() => {
 await ... //fetch some data
}
```

But what is a working syntax for unnamed async function? Should we use IIFE here to call it?

Comment: what about `test()`?

Comment: An IIFE to build it works but why do you want a real anonymous function ?

Comment: You can simply omit the name for it to be anonymous

Comment: yes you can do an IIFE .But anonymous functions make debugging hard and stack trace hard to read. You should name you function when possible :)

Comment: Actually, your snippet already *is* an anonymous async function. It's not a named function.

Answer (score 4):

two way,

1. simple way

```js
!async function () {
    console.log("e",'yibu');
}();
```

or

```js
(async  () => {
    console.log("e",'yibu');
})();

//maybe this is better then above
;(async function () {
    console.log("e",'yibu');
}());

//this is allmost same
;[ async function () {
    console.log("e",'yibu');
}()];
```

2. use [then] this is not absolute "anonymous"

```js
var x=async  () => 100;

x().then(
    e=>console.log({e})
);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const test = async (asyncFunc) => {
    return await asyncFunc()
}

test(async () => { 
    return "Hello World!"
}).then(console.log)
```

Comment: `return await` is never necessary in Javascript.

Comment: @lonesomeday FYI, that's true in 99% of cases, and in this case, but not if you're using it inside a `try` block.

Comment: @loganfsmyth While this is true and I concede the technical point, the sequence of operations is potentially confusing enough that I would immediately refactor any code I came across where it was done!

Comment: It has advantages and disadvantages. I like to write it that way because it's a nice indicator telling you that the function is async. If, for example, you decide to assign the resolved value to a variable instead of doing a return directly, you don't have to check the implementation first to see if it's async or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
async function() => {
   await ... 
}
```

Comment: async function() => { 1} 
VM3385:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (